# Time series forecasting statsmodel error. What does distrvs want? What is it used for?

Tags: python, time-series

Method 1:
    rng_state = np.random.RandomState()

```
arparams = np.array([ar_lag1, ar_lag2, ar_lag3, ar_lag4])
arparams = arparams[:ar_order]
maparams = np.array([ma_lag1, ma_lag2, ma_lag3, ma_lag4])
maparams = maparams[:ma_order]


ar = np.r_[1, -arparams] # add zero-lag and negate
ma = np.r_[1, maparams] # add zero-lag
```

## Arma generate sample

```
y = sm.tsa.arma_generate_sample(ar, ma, n_samp, sigma=sigma, distrvs=rng_state.randn, burnin=burnin)
```

## This method generates TypeError: randn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'

Method 2:

```
dist = lambda n: np.random.standard_t(3, size=n)
# np.random.seed(8659567)
```

Arma generate sample
    x = arma_generate_sample(ar, ma, nobs, sigma=1, distrvs=dist,
                             burnin=500)

```
# This method gives me TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `distrvs` argument to `sm.tsa.arma_generate_sample` must be a function that takes `size` (literally) as a parameter -- the function is called with a named argument.  (See the code in `statsmodels/tsa/arima_process.py` in your installation)

For example for your Method 2 test change the argument name to `size`:

```
dist = lambda size: np.random.standard_t(3, size=size)
```

Comment: This approach works however could there be a way to work out first method. As I could use this practically. That would be great if you could help me out over here.